# How find min and max and group by id?

Tags: ravendb

I need to find the minimum and maximum date from the list of dates. How can I do it? I use **ravendb**
I do following:

```
from 'event' as e
where e.Header.Name in ('territory_entry', 'territory_exit')
and e.Payload.Id in ('123', '456')
select {
    Lines: e.Lines.map(l => {
      return {
          maxTime: Math.max(e.Header.Timestamp)
      }
    })
}
```

But.. It doesn't work

For example,
I have list of objects:

```
['123', territory_entry, '2022-04-06T12:31:13']
['123', territory_exit, '2022-04-06T13:31:13']
['123', territory_entry, '2022-04-06T14:31:13']
['456', territory_entry, '2022-04-06T12:31:13']
['456', territory_exit, '2022-04-06T13:31:13']
['456', territory_entry, '2022-04-06T14:31:13']
```

And all I need is return minimum entry by id and maximum entry by id
query should return this:

```
min: ['123', territory_entry, '2022-04-06T12:31:13'], ['456', territory_entry, '2022-04-06T12:31:13']
max: ['123', territory_exit, '2022-04-06T13:31:13'], ['456', territory_exit, '2022-04-06T13:31:13']
```

rql doesn't have join etc, js functions don’t help me in this situation so I don't understand. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a map/reduce index.

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/indexes/map-reduce-indexes#example-i---count